# Conditional Where clauses in LInq to Entities returns all columns

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am using conditional where clauses in linq to entities as below

```
    Dim q = (From x In ctx.Product)

    If mySearchField = SearchField.ProductId Then
       q = q.Where(Function(y) y.ProductId = mySearchTerm)
    ElseIf s.SearchField = SearchField.ProductCode Then
       q = q.Where(Function(y) y.ProductCode = mySearchTerm)
    ElseIf s.SearchField = SearchField.ProductName Then
       q = q.Where(Function(y) y.ProductName = mySearchTerm)
    End If

Dim productIds As List(Of Integer) = (From x In q Select x.ProductId).ToList
```

However when i view the generated sql via

```
Debug.Print(DirectCast(q, System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery(Of Product)).ToTraceString)
```

The generated sql shows that it selects all three columns of the product class when all I need to return is ProductId.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
[Extent1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
[Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName]
FROM (SELECT 
      [Product].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
      [Product].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
      [Product].[ProductName] AS [ProductName]
      FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Product]) AS [Extent1]
```

Is there anyway of forcing EF to only select the columns I specify but keep the conditional where clauses on any property I need on the Product class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your Where clause dynamically as an Expression, and then apply the expression at the same time as you select the data from the Linq Context.

```
Dim MyWhereExpr As Expression(Of Func(Of Product, Bool))
MyWhereExpr = Function(y) True

If ... Then
    MyWhereExpr = Function(y) y.ProductId = mySearchTerm
ElseIf ...

Dim productIds As List(Of Integer) = _
    ctx.Product.Where(MyWhereExpr).Select(Function(y) y.ProductId).ToList
```

Comment: Doesn't MyWhereExpr need to be of type System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of Product, Boolean)) to apply the clause on the product class - which cannot be passed into the Where function as that requires Expression(Of Func(Of String, Boolean))

Comment: I rearranged the order of the Where and Select which should fix that.  According to my experimenting, this should work.  Note that also by having it all in one query instead of creating q in the beginning, I avoid the sub-query select as well.

Comment: Also, I am a C# programmer, not VB.Net, so the syntax may not be exactly right.  Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. I like the idea of building on just the expression and not the entire iqueryable object itself.